Can't scrape links from the dynamic website using Selenium
I'm trying to collect links to personal profiles and contacts from the following website:
https://www.dlapiper.com/en-us/people#t=All&sort=relevancy&numberOfResults=100&f:CountriesID=[United%20Kingdom]
I'm using Selenium to do scraping via chromedriver and normally it works just fine - however, for this particular website I can't get to the source html where all the links to people's profiles would be visible.
I wrote a standard script which would normally work for any other dynamic website.
links = []
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.dlapiper.com/en-gb/people#t=All&sort=%40lastname%20ascending&f:CountriesID=[United%20Kingdom]')
time.sleep(5)
cookies_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler")
cookies_button.click()
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
time.sleep(5)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
parse = soup.find_all('a')
for item in parse:
    links.append(item.get('href'))
print(links)

However, links from the people search block can't get into the driver.page_source - even though I can find all the link elements when I press "inspect" in Chrome. I have tried increasing the time.sleep(), did not help.
I understand that there are lots of javascripts being executed on this page - maybe I need to activate some of them manually? Help would be much appreciated as I don't know Javascript.

The lawyer's contact details are in an iframe...
1   Frame ID    myIframe
2   Frame Name  Unused
3   Frame Title People Index Hosted Search Page
4   Frame Source    https://www.dlapiper.com/en-US/coveosearchpages/people%20index%20hosted%20search%20page#t=All&sort=relevancy&f:CountriesID=[United%20States]
5   Frame Domain    www.dlapiper.com
6   Type    text/html
7   Mode    CSS1Compat
8   Language    en
9   Encoding    UTF-8
10  Modified    06/03/2024 19:25:06
11  Load Time   2.52 seconds
12  Source Size 361 bytes
13  Position    0 - 291 pixels
14  Viewport    1903 x 1500 pixels

Is your script scanning inside child frames?

Thanks, yes, the goal is to get to the personal profile link that is located inside a class="CoveoResultLink" element. Just scanning through the main search page would not be enough. Can you elaborate a bit on the extract you have just pasted? This looks new to me


Can you elaborate a bit on the extract you have just pasted? This
looks new to me

That table comes from the Classic browser which exposes iframes and offers lots of tech info among many other things… including custom tags, hidden scripts, shadow doms, global identifiers, functions, objects, and so forth.
It can scrape pretty much anything upon request, but there’s no automated bot as such to set up… still though it’s very powerful for inspecting websites and making the right decisions to set up your bot.
Up until last year I had it for public download on a home site but I got tired of website maintenance after 6-7 years of hard work and pulled the plug!
Goof luck with everything.

can you see a link to iframe in this browser? in chrome i see , which is an empty src link and is entirely not helpful as the tutorial suggests I should request the src link to get to the iframe content.

I can see all iframes on a page because it draws a thin bar at the top of them and I then just right-click on this bar and get a table of tech details. Just navigate to this link…
https://www.dlapiper.com/en-us/coveosearchpages/people-index-hosted-search-page#t=All&sort=relevancy&f:CountriesID=[United%20States]

You’re wasting your time with junk commercial browsers like FF and Chrome… you need to get a decent “underground” browser that exposes everything to help you out.
